# How to initalize parameter from Amazon Web Services?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I have a question about getting parameter from amazon web services and what is the best way to do this ? I would like to hold connection string in private string. In my opinion it would be better if it was `private const string JookliConnectionString`, but I do not have idea how to solve this, because `GetParameterAsync` this method takes a while. I tried to do this all in constructor but is not possible, because in this case when I debug I see that it jumps into services configuration and there tries to perform service which downloads JookliConnectionString which is null at this time.

```
private string JookliConnectionString = "";

public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            ConfigureLogger();
            _configuration = ConfigurationBuilder(webHostEnvironment).Result;
        }

        public async Task<IConfiguration> ConfigurationBuilder(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            var environment = webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName.ToLower();

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Just for test here", "just for test here");
            var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1);

            var request = new GetParameterRequest()
            {
                Name = $"/{environment}/myapp/ConnectionString"
            };

            var value = await client.GetParameterAsync(request: request);
            JookliConnectionString = value.Parameter.Value;

            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            var configuration = builder.Build();

            _apiLogger.Information("Connection string: " + configuration[JookliConnectionString]);
            AuthorizationChecker.CheckAllEndpoints();
            _apiLogger.Information("Connected");

            return configuration;
        }
```

I tried to find some useful stuff but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [.NET extensions for configuration from AWS?](https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-extensions-configuration)
It makes the configuration with a parameter store simpler for .NET Core and may be helpful.

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddSystemsManager("/aws/reference/secretsmanager/SomeSecret");
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```